# lightroom editing in photoshop..

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

I am sending my lightroom images in small groups to be edited in photoshop.  I'm selecting to edit the original image.  When I save the image (jpg) in photoshop, only some of the images in lightroom from the batch are updated.  If I go into the develop mode in Lightroom I can see the changes there but can't seem to get the changes in the library part.  I end up having to individually go back into editing the pics I've already edited in photoshop again, it comes up straight away with the final look and I make a small change, save it and the changes then translate to lightroom library.  It seems like a bug between lightroom and photoshop. Any ideas anyone?  it's very annoying!
thanks, 
Nikki

Comment: What version of Lightroom and Photoshop are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is not updated instantaneously. Also, folders are not continuously being scanned. Do all your changes, then do a manual synchronization on the folder.

Also, enabling maximal compatibility mode in Photoshop might help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Lightroom is not seeing the updates you are making in Photoshop right away, here is my workflow that has worked 100% of the time for me. I am using Photoshop CC and Lightrtoom 5 but it also worked perfectly with Photoshop CS6 and all previous versions of Lightroom.

1. In Lightroom right-click the image I want to edit in Photoshop "Edit > Edit In Adobe Photoshop"
2. I edit the file in Photoshop then use command+s to save the file. It is important to not save the file using "save as" or saving it as a different name or file format. WIth my preference it is saved as a "PSD" file with a name like "originalname-Edit.psd"
3. Then I close the file in Photoshop and go back to Lightroom
   By the time I get back to Lightroom the edited picture is there for further Lightroom editing.